# AngularJs cascading dropdown list in a form that needs selected when page loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cascadingdropdown

Loving AngularJs but stuck at the moment with a typical scenario that should have been common to most applications. I, however, just cannot find a solution after having researched/played around for almost 6 hours!

Basically, my form has two drop down lists and the 'Areas' select option loads after a region has been selected:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Regions</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedRegion.Id" ng-options="r.Id as r.Description for r in regions" ng-change="GetAreas(selectedRegion.Id)">
                <option value="">Please select a region..</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Areas</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedArea.Id" ng-options="a.Id as a.Description for a in areas">
                <option value="">Please select an area..</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

In my controller, first I get the parent model which is let's say "customer" that was saved in a previous 'Create' View. This customer model has a RegionId and an AreaId which when loading the above 'Edit' view, I need to be selected.

I achieved this by this JS code:

```
manageCustomerRepository.getCustomer($routeParams.customerId).then(function(mainDetails) {
        $scope.customer = mainDetails;

        masterDataRepository.GetRegions().then(function (regionList) {
            $scope.regions = regionList;
            var index;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.regions.length; i++) {
                var currentRegion = $scope.regions[i];
                if (currentRegion.Id === parseInt($scope.customer.RegionId)) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $scope.selectedRegion = $scope.regions[index];
        });

        masterDataRepository.GetAreas($scope.customer.RegionId).then(function (areaList) {
            $scope.areas = areaList;
            var index;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.regions.length; i++) {
                var currentArea = $scope.areas[i];
                if (currentArea.Id === parseInt($scope.customer.AreaId)) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $scope.selectedArea = $scope.areas[index];
        });
    });
```

when the Edit view gets loaded, I am able to get all the regions and areas for the regions and get the RegionId and AreaId from the customer object and select the options that are right. However, I cannot seem to be able to change the selected region. The option's selected='selected' attribute does not change and I cannot get them to change the value!

Also, I'm not entirely sure that when I post the form back with ng-model='selectedRegion.Id' and selectedArea.Id, I will have a customer object in my angular controller.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is `$scope.customer.RegionId` always set to a region? If not, `index` will remain undefined, and `$scope.regions[index]` will be undefined as well. `$scope.selectedRegion = $scope.regions[index] || {};` might handle that case.

Comment: @Ninsly yes, $scope.customer.RegionId is always expected to be set. The current state of the JS allows me to set the selectedRegion and  Area but there is some rather bizarre behavior in that the region ddl won't change even if the user selects a value other than the one set during page load

Comment: Ever get this working?

Comment: @AdamWilson unfortunately it just disappeared by itself. We suspected it might be a browser issue (perhaps with a specific version). Not a lot of complaints from users so it did not justify spending more time to get to the bottom of this. Personally, I still would have but I have moved on to NG2 which has more awesomeness than ver1! We have also started using TypeScript. Sorry, I know this doesn't help you!